# How can I change WPF Button Image in Setter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I have a very strange problem trying to change the controltemplate for a button in WPF (c#).

I now have the following code:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MacOSX-Close" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="Black" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Image x:Name="bgimg" Source="bin/debug/Ressources/Images/GUI/frame-btn-defaulted.png"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="bgimg" Property="Source" Value="bin/debug/Ressources/Images/GUI/frame-btn-defaulted.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

So this isn't working. It says

```
    "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" is no valid value for property "System.Windows.Controls.Image.Source" on a setter.
```

And when I tried using multiple images in a grid (because you can only set one child) and modified the "visibility" property, the button didn't show up at all!!! No button, no image. And, yes, I am sure the image exists.
But the source is relative to the solution root, not to the compiled program... does this matter? Please help me :) I'm gettin' little desperate here... :(

Best regards ;)
And please ask if somethin's not clear to you.

Comment: `Image.Source` is a bitmap image, not a string. Use a converter and have it create a bitmap based on the file name and bind to that.

Comment: Are you sure? The IDE does indeed show the image when I provide the path! It's just that it can't seem to find the location because during development the path must be relative to the XAML file but at runtime the path has to be relative to the *.exe startup location.
But if it comes to use a converter... how would I bind to it? I tried it one and it could not seem to find it...

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Note that WPF has built-in type conversion from `string` to `ImageSource`. It is perfectly valid to apply an URL string (e.g. a relative file name) to an Image's `Source` property in XAML.

Comment: @Clemens You're right... forgot about that until I actually tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder like say Resources in your project and put image in your resources folder and their build action should be set to Resource. Then you can set Source = "/Resources/frame-btn-defaulted.png"

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "create folder 'xyz' in your project"?
Should I put it in the solutions root folder OR should I put it in 'bin/debug/'? The problem is that (at runtime) the program runs out of the /bin/debug/ folder but the xaml file is located two levels higher and so the program has no chance to access this file at runtime... well, I don't want something like having to navigate up to C:\ level to use relative paths in the xaml file...

Comment: put it in project folder and make sure that once you add images to that folder, the build action of images should be set to Resource. It will work.